# Codeigniter - PHP array return a single data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I've a file uploader. I do the overwrite through the data. It makes me upload these data:
- Pict1.jpg
- Pict12.jpg
- Pict13.jpg

But when I tried to return it, its only showing pict1.jpg. Here the code

**Controller:**

```
function send(){
        $mariupload = $this->upload_gambar($_FILES['gambar']);
        if ($mariupload === FALSE) {
            $upload = false;
        }

        if($upload = false){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        } else {
            $dataupload = $mariupload;
            echo $dataupload;
        }

    private function upload_gambar($files){
        //config buat upload gambar
        $config['upload_path'] = 'path to upload';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']     = '1024';
        $config['overwrite'] = '0';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $gambar = array();
        if (is_array($files['name']) || is_object($files['name'])){
            foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $gambar) {
                $_FILES['gambar[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

                $fileName = $gambar;

                $images[] = $fileName;

                $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('gambar[]')) {
                    $dataupload = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                    return $dataupload.'<br>';
                } else {
                    $mariupload = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try to echo $dataupload in upload_gambar function, it works as an array. But its returning as a single data to send() function. Any idea?

Comment: edited the $mariupload. But when i change gambar[] into gambar, it turns NULL. I have a 5 single uploader that will be combine into 1 array in 1 time submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Thanks to Jovi Wang on Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/jovi.wang.96?fref=ufi) . This is the clean code:

```
function send(){
        $try = $this->upload_multiple($_FILES['gambar']);
                if(!$try = false){
                $anu= $this->upload_multiple($_FILES['gambar']);
                foreach($anu as $key => $anu2){
                echo $anu2.'<br>';
                }
}

public function upload_multiple($files)
    {
        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($files);
        // echo '</pre>';

        $config['upload_path']      = 'path to upload';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']         = 1024;
        $config['overwrite']        = 0;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $data = array();

        foreach($files['name'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if ( ! empty($files['name'][$key]))
            {
                $_FILES['gambar_single']['name'] = $files['name'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar_single']['name'] = $files['name'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar_single']['type'] = $files['type'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar_single']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar_single']['error'] = $files['error'][$key];
                $_FILES['gambar_single']['size'] = $files['size'][$key];

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('gambar_single'))
                {
                    $data[] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                }
                else
                {
                    $data[] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $data[] = 'empty upload';
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending just single file

```
$mariupload = $this->upload_gambar($_FILES['gambar']);
```

change this to

```
$mariupload = $this->upload_gambar($_FILES);
```

then in your **upload_gambar** handle it as **foreach**

Comment: Undefined index: name in upload_gambar function

Answer (score 0):

You have a return inside the loop. A return will interrupt the loop as the function will not continue to be executed. Try to feed up an array instead.

Replace

```
return $dataupload.'<br>';
```

With

```
 $return[] = $dataupload;
```

And at the end of the function append:

```
return $return;
```

Comment: its gives array on upload_gambar() but returning a single file in send() :(